# How to integrate live Skype status in my application?

Tags: c#

I have a webpage where a person's Skypename is present along with a Skype icon.By clicking on the button it will open Skype.But now I want to add live Skype Status i.e showing if the person is online or offline or busy,etc.I want to show this through a changing image button

Answer (score 3):

Standard Skype buttons can detect and show the status of the user. [Have a look here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/). If you wanted the status to be real-time, you could refresh it using AJAX.

However, if you prefer to handle the code yourself, you can easily retrieve your skype status by using

```
http://mystatus.skype.com/nnnn.num
```

where nnnn is the Skype name you're interested in. It returns the following:

0 – unknown 
1 – offline 
2 – online 
3 – away 
4 – not available 
5 – do not disturb 
6 – invisible 
7 – skype me