# Is it still possible to get Skype's user online status?

Tags: api, skype

As the title says, is it still possible to check a user's status (online, offline, busy...) on Skype after the (big) change in its API service? Developers section seems very very limited now: http://developer.skype.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

There are some urls wich can be used to detect the online status.

> This gives a text with the statusname (e.g. away or online)

http://mystatus.skype.com/SKYPENAME.txt

> This gives you a numeric skype statuscode (see list below)

http://mystatus.skype.com/SKYPENAME.num

> This gives an xml output including numeric statuscode and statustext
>   in diffent languages

http://mystatus.skype.com/SKYPENAME.xml

> At last you have urls which show diffent status icon images:
>
> Replace "smallicon" or "smallclassic" with the image you like.
>   (Possible values: balloon, bigclassic, smallclassic, smallicon,
>   mediumicon, dropdown-white, dropdown-trans)

http://mystatus.skype.com/smallicon/SKYPENAME
http://mystatus.skype.com/smallclassic/SKYPENAME
http://mystatus.skype.com/SKYPENAME

In PHP The best way is to use my function:

```
  /**
   * @version: 1.0 (2014-05-13
   *
   * @param: String $username             Skype Username
   * @param: [String $lang]               Languagecode (possible values 2014-05-13: "en", "fr", "de","ja", "zh-cn", "zh-tw", "pt", "pt-br", "it", "es", "pl" , "pl"
   * @param: [String $img_time]           Typ im Status Image wich you like to show (Possible values: 2014-05-13: balloon, bigclassic, smallclassic, smallicon, mediumicon, dropdown-white, dropdown-trans)
   *
   * @return array                        "num" = Skype Statuscode, "text" = Statustext (Away" ect.), "img_url" url to Statuscode Image
   */
  function getSkypeStatus($username, $lang = "de", $img_type = "mediumicon")
  {
    $url = "http://mystatus.skype.com/".$username.".xml";
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);

    $status = array();
    if($data === false)
    {
      $status = array("num" =>0,
                      "text"=>"http error"
                );
      if(isset($http_response_header)) $status["error_info"] = $http_response_header;
    }
    else
    {
      $pattern = '/xml:lang="NUM">(.*)</';
      preg_match($pattern,$data, $match);

      $status["num"] = $match[1];

      $pattern = '/xml:lang="' . $lang .'">(.*)</';
      preg_match($pattern,$data, $match);

      $status["text"]    = $match[1];
      $status["img_url"] = "http://mystatus.skype.com/".$img_type."/".$username;
    }
    return $status;
  }
```

Usage:

```
$status = getSkypeStatus("YourSkypeName"); // Minimal
$status = getSkypeStatus("YourSkypeName","de");  // with defined language for Statustext
$status = getSkypeStatus("YourSkypeName","de", "mediumicon"); // with specified image 

// to display status Icon:

echo '<img src="'.$status["img_url"].'" alt="'.$status["text"].'" title="'.$status["text"].'">';


// or if you like to do you own code for different status

switch($status["num"])
{
  case 7:
  case 2: echo "You are online"; break;
  default: echo "you are offline or in away state";
}
```

Possible Status messages (in english) are

- http error:     Error to get the api data e.g. problems with internet
- connection Unknown:        Not opted in or no data available. Offline:
- The user is Offline Online:         The user is Online Away:
- The user is Away Not Available:  The user is Not Available Do Not
- Disturb: The user is Do Not Disturb (DND)
- Invisible:      The user is Invisible or appears Offline
- Skype Me:       The user is in Skype Me
  mode

Possible numeric Statuscodes:

- case 0 = Unknown
- case 1 = Offline
- case 2 = Online
- case 3 = Away
- case 4 = Not Available
- case 5 = Do Not Disturb
- case 6 = Invisible
- case 7 = Skype Me

I god these informations from following threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16320950/2377961
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426418/2377961

Comment: What if I have a dot in my username?

Comment: It should also work if your name includes a dot. If not try the function from Boann here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12093450/2377961 it should replace everything with the html % code.

Comment: http://mystatus.skype.com/smallicon/<skype login> link not works: <html><body><b>Http/1.1 Service Unavailable</b></body> </html>

Comment: Hmm ... maybe microsoft changed this api too after they bought skype :(

Comment: Those URLs don't appear to work anymore for me... DNS error I believe.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE 2014-12-19:**

It is important to know: checking a skype status works ONLY if the user has enabled "my status in internet" or "Mein Status darf im Netz veröffentlicht werden" (in german).
Otherwise the status is alway "offline"

Answer (score 6):

## Feature is not supported since May 2015

The checkbox disappeared from Skype Options.

Source: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA605/how-do-i-set-up-the-skype-button-to-show-my-status-on-the-web-in-skype-for-windows-desktop